# Automatic Type Conversions in casbah for Bigdecimal

Tags: scala, serialization, bigdecimal, casbah

I need to serialize `scala.math.BigDecimal`values using `casbah` automatic type conversions.

I've imported this

```
 import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.conversions.scala._
```

and call those methods within the class.

```
  RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()
  DeregisterJodaLocalDateTimeConversionHelpers()
```

But it says, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class scala.math.BigDecimal.

Isn't `casbah` support for `Bigdecimal` serialization or any other way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write and register your own serializer.  BigDecimal is not supported by bson - see the [supported types](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification).

The challenge is how to store the type so you can query against it effectively and how best to convert it back on deserialisation (without blanket converting of all types).